# How to dynamically create or populate a table from a masterlist in another sheet?

Tags: numbers

I have a table with 500+ rows in Sheet 1 (let's call this "masterlist".

In another sheet, I'd like to be able use a drop-down cell containing certain key values (all taken from a single column in the masterlist), to subsequently populate a table with all the rows match that match.

Ironically I can do this effortlessly in MySQL but alas I need to produce a spreadsheet on this occasion and I am nub. For those savvy with SQL, a more succinct description of the problem is:

SELECT * FROM `tableA` WHERE `tableA`.`id_column` = 'target value'

Though, to be fair, since the size of selected output is unknown, I also don't understand how to populate the receiving table (in Numbers) with an unknown number of rows.

Comment: This is a prefect example of how spreadsheets are fundamentally different from proper databases.  There are several articles on the reasons for the difference available on the Internet.  Cheers!